# how to hide mounted drives in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I'm using an external hardDisk that contains 4 drives when I connect it to my pc it is showing four icons in the taskbar. I want to hide these type of mounted drives.

##### I have tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop volumes-visible 'false'
```

##### traceback

```
No such schema “org.gnome.nautilus.desktop”
```

#### I don't want to install gnome and any other external libs

Answer (score 1):

Enter `ctrl` + `alt` + `T` to launch terminal

###### Hide mounted drives icon like pendrive or external hardisk

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
```

###### Show mounted devices like pendrive or external hardisk

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts true
```